# Why can't I read in this react material theme in my code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am learning react and now I have this Theme thing that does not work.

**This code works ok i can toggle among 10 different Themes:**

```js
    import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
    import allThemes from './index';
    
    const ThemeContext = createContext({});
    const lastThemeIndex = allThemes.length - 1;
    const ThemeContextProvider = props => {
        const [theme, setTheme] = useState();
        const [themeName, setThemeName] = useState(allThemes[0].name);
    
        const setThemeType = () => {
            const themeIndex = allThemes.findIndex(t => t.name === themeName);
            const nextTheme = allThemes[themeIndex === lastThemeIndex ? 0 : themeIndex + 1];
            setTheme({ ...nextTheme.theme });
            setThemeName(nextTheme.name);
        };
    
        return (
            <ThemeContext.Provider
                value={{
                    themeName,
                    setThemeType,
                }}
            >
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{props.children}</ThemeProvider>
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
        );
    };
    
    export default ThemeContext;
    export { ThemeContextProvider };
```

**But when I add this useEffect hook it stoped working. I want to save the User selected Theme in `localStorage` and in the `useEffect` load it back in. But it's not working as the image error show**

```js
    import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
    import allThemes from './index';
    
    const ThemeContext = createContext({});
    const lastThemeIndex = allThemes.length - 1;
    const ThemeContextProvider = props => {
        const [theme, setTheme] = useState();
        const [themeName, setThemeName] = useState(allThemes[0].name);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const yourTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
            if (yourTheme) {
                const themeIndex = allThemes.findIndex(t => t.name === yourTheme);
                const selectedTheme = allThemes[themeIndex];
                setTheme(selectedTheme);
            } else {
                setTheme(allThemes[0].theme);
            }
        });
    
        const setThemeType = () => {
            const themeIndex = allThemes.findIndex(t => t.name === themeName);
            const nextTheme = allThemes[themeIndex === lastThemeIndex ? 0 : themeIndex + 1];
            setTheme({ ...nextTheme.theme });
            setThemeName(nextTheme.name);
            persistThemeType(nextTheme.name);
        };
    
        function persistThemeType(name) {
            localStorage.setItem('theme', name);
        }
    
        return (
            <ThemeContext.Provider
                value={{
                    themeName,
                    setThemeType,
                }}
            >
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{props.children}</ThemeProvider>
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
        );
    };
    
    export default ThemeContext;
    export { ThemeContextProvider };
```

[image]

**This the Theme's:**

```js
    import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import shadows from './shadows';
    import typography from './typography';
    
    const Caregiver = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
            primary: {
                dark: '#a84632',
                main: '#f16548',
                light: '#f3836c',
            },
            action: {
                active: '#f16548',
            },
        },
        typography,
        shadows,
        overrides: {
            MuiButtonBase: {
                text: {
                    color: 'blue', // Some CSS
                },
            },
        },
    });
    
    const Creator = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
            primary: {
                dark: '#ac6613',
                main: '#f7921c',
                light: '#f8a749',
            },
            action: {
                active: '#f7921c',
            },
        },
        typography,
        shadows,
    });
    
    const Explorer = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
            primary: {
                dark: '#5a5b20',
                main: '#81822e',
                light: '#9a9b57',
            },
            action: {
                active: '#81822e',
            },
        },
        typography,
        shadows,
    });
    
    const Hero = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
            primary: {
                dark: '#004877',
                main: '#0067ab',
                light: '#3385bb',
            },
            action: {
                active: '#0067ab',
            },
        },
        typography,
        shadows,
    });
    
    const Innocent = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
            primary: {
                dark: '#007a9a',
                main: '#00afdd',
                light: '#33bfe3',
            },
            action: {
                active: '#00afdd',
            },
        },
        typography,
        shadows,
    });
    
    const Jester = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
            primary: {
                dark: '#738f27',
                main: '#a5cd39',
                light: '#b7d760',
            },
            action: {
                active: '#a5cd39',
            },
        },
        typography,
        shadows,
    });
    
    const Lover = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
            primary: {
                dark: '#971f48',
                main: '#d92d68',
                light: '#e05786',
            },
            action: {
                active: '#d92d68',
            },
        },
        typography,
        shadows,
    });
    
    const Magician = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
            primary: {
                dark: '#651a63',
                main: '#91268e',
                light: '#a751a4',
            },
            action: {
                active: '#91268e',
            },
        },
        typography,
        shadows,
    });
    
    const Everyperson = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
            primary: {
                dark: '#006369',
                main: '#008e97',
                light: '#33a4ab',
            },
            action: {
                active: '#008e97',
            },
        },
        typography,
        shadows,
    });
    
    const Revolutionary = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
            primary: {
                dark: '#8f1b27',
                main: '#cd2738',
                light: '#d7525f',
            },
            action: {
                active: '#cd2738',
            },
        },
        typography,
        shadows,
    });
    
    const Ruler = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
            primary: {
                dark: '#a18005',
                main: '#e7b708',
                light: '#ebc539',
            },
            action: {
                active: '#e7b708',
            },
        },
        typography,
        shadows,
    });
    
    const Sage = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
            primary: {
                dark: '#5a331e',
                main: '#81492c',
                light: '#9a6d56',
            },
            action: {
                active: '#81492c',
            },
        },
        typography,
        shadows,
    });
    
    const allThemes = [
        { name: 'Caregiver', theme: Caregiver },
        { name: 'Creator', theme: Creator },
        { name: 'Explorer', theme: Explorer },
        { name: 'Hero', theme: Hero },
        { name: 'Innocent', theme: Innocent },
        { name: 'Jester', theme: Jester },
        { name: 'Lover', theme: Lover },
        { name: 'Magician', theme: Magician },
        { name: 'Everyperson', theme: Everyperson },
        { name: 'Revolutionary', theme: Revolutionary },
        { name: 'Ruler', theme: Ruler },
        { name: 'Sage', theme: Sage },
    ];
    
    export default allThemes;
```

Comment: Can you host this code on the codesandbox? It would be easier to pinpoint the error!

Answer (score 0):

#### useState needs an initial value for the first render

```js
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(allThemes[0].theme);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const yourTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
        if (yourTheme) {
            const themeIndex = allThemes.findIndex(t => t.name === yourTheme);
            const selectedTheme = allThemes[themeIndex];
            setTheme(selectedTheme);
        }
    });
```

I've removed the `useEffect`'s `else` block and placed it's value in the default for `theme`. Otherwise, the first render of this component will have `theme === null`.

Comment: Thanks I tried this but I still get like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'primary' of undefined`. The theme is not applied

Comment: It's like the  `useEffect` has no affect

Answer (score 0):

Just silly mistake like:

```
setTheme(selectedTheme);
```

should be:

```
setTheme(selectedTheme.theme);
```